# webpage to control a ros system

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The goal is to build a webpage with ***3 image topics***[AKA web streams] and ***2 client nodes***(AKA inputs for the user accessing the webpage) of a ros system.

1. Is this even possible?
2. If yes, what exactly do i do? I have no experience in web stuff.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284400/webpage-to-control-a-ros-system/) by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
The typical answer to these types of questions is: yes, use [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) together with [RobotWebTools](http://robotwebtools.org). That would allow you to create something from scratch.

There are some precooked solutions that use the above, but if you ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
.. have no experience in web development using any of that is going to be difficult. It might help if you can describe what your actual goal is: what is this web application supposed to do / allow?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
For industrial applications and HMIs, [flexgui](https://www.ppm.no/flexgui4-Home) might be an option. It's ROS integrated and targeted specifically at industrial interfaces. The basic variant is also open-source: [flexgui_industrial](https://github.com/ros-industrial/flexgui_industrial).

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2018-03-05**:
Not industrial. Just for a prototype for my project.

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2018-03-19**:
I have a ROS system with a couple of cameras, a mobile base & a robotic arm. I have 2 servers one for the base and one for the arm. I need to build a webpage/application which links to this ros system and must contain 3 web streams & 2 user inputs which link to the ros servers(aka ros-clients)

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2018-03-19**:
Seems like ros web tools should be a good enough system for now. Thanks for you help @gvdhoorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[RobotWebTools](http://robotwebtools.org/tools.html)

---

Originally posted by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) with karma: 55 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0